# Android Fragment layout is out of screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-relativelayout

So I've got a TabbedActivity with an additional class extending fragment but the list just won't stay inside my screen.

[image: List item out of screen]

As you may see there should be an additional H at the screen's bottom.

Here's my fragment layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context=".CreateGameActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:text="@string/create_game_participants_tab_title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listParticipants"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textNoParticipants"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/listParticipants"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="@string/no_participants"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

which is loaded by following onCreateView() method

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_game_participants_layout, container, false);

ListView listParticipants = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listParticipants);
TextView textNoParticipants = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textNoParticipants);

List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey("participants"))
    list.addAll((List<String>)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("participants"));
else {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("participants", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    list.addAll(prefs.getStringSet("lastParticipants", new HashSet<>()));
}

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, list);
listParticipants.setAdapter(adapter);

SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener touchListener = new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener(
        listParticipants,
        new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.DismissCallbacks {
            boolean canDismiss(int position) {
                return true;
            }

            void onDismiss(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                for (int position : reverseSortedPositions)
                    list.removeAt(position);
            }
        });
listParticipants.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
listParticipants.setOnScrollListener(touchListener.makeScrollListener());

return view;
```

Fragments are created using their constructor and loaded in activities onCreate() by

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_game_activity_tabbed)

Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
supportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
viewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
```

And finally my tabbed activities layout.xml is defined like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="janniskaiser.matchplanner.CreateGameActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_ok" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: It should scroll down till your `H`.

Comment: It should yes, but as you may see from the light blue half arc on my screen's bottom, it does not.

Comment: Where is the data coming from? Where do you store it in your bundle/shared preferences?

Comment: The data is in this case coming from the sharedPrefs lastParticipants StringSet

Comment: I think you missed to post the relevant code. Do you include your layout.xml in a parent layout?

Comment: Added my complete tabbed activities layout

Comment: You have given padding to the main layout of the Fragment and given margin to the top textview, thats why it happens like this.

Comment: I removed all paddings and margins in my fragments layout.xml and the error still persists

Answer (score 1):

Change the `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` attribute of your  **Toolbar** to `app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"`. this should fix it.